# VB compilation error, expected identifier

Tags: vb.net

Below is the code for a script to download a zip file from a website, but I get a compilation error that states 'expected identifier'.

```
Public Class DownloadAddrFile
    Public Function DownloadFile(ByVal Addr As String, ByVal SaveAddrFile As String) As Boolean
        Try 
            Dim WC As New System.Net.WebClient()
            WC.DownloadFile(Addr, SaveAddrFile)
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function
End Class

Call DownloadFile("http://data.gdeltproject.org/events/index.html/20171002.export.CSV.zip", "C:\Users\mwhiting\Documents\Zip_files\data.zip")
```

Any help on how to make this work would be great!

Comment: `Call DownloadFile("http://data.gdeltproject.org/events/index.html/20171002.export.CSV.zip", "C:\Users\mwhiting\Documents\Zip_files\data.zip")` is out of context. It's not in an executable part of the code. When would you expect this to run? It needs to be within a constructor or method which can be triggered by something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call a method inside a [Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/namespaces).

Create an instance of Class `DownloadAddrFile` and for example inside a button-click call the method `DownloadFile`.
(The [`Call`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/call-statement)-keyword is usually not required)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim d As New DownloadAddrFile
    d.DownloadFile("http://data.gdeltproject.org/events/index.html/20171002.export.CSV.zip", "C:\Users\mwhiting\Documents\Zip_files\data.zip")
End Sub
```